# Cocoa NSWindow keep title bar in fullscreen

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, titlebar

I would like to know how to keep the title bar (and the buttons) in fullscreen. Basically, it is hidden, and you need to move your cursor to the top to make the title bar visible. But Google Chrome, keep the title bar. 
Any idea, how to do that?

**Update with screenshots :**

Chrome in fullscreen

[image]

Chrome in fullscreen, with the cursor on top :

[image]

in both cases, the buttons are still visible.

Comment: Not even chrome title bar is shown on full-screen mode. If you are saying maximise than it can be done. Please show screenshot for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is not really conform to Apple UI guidelines but the only way to get such behaviour is to hide the default window buttons and to implement them by yourself. Of course this will require to set the appeariance in different modes ( window active/deactiv) and dependent on mouse location.

To get the window standard buttons too place them at a different location in the content view of the window will not be enough since there will be hidden and displayed in the window title bar during fullscreen mode.

The action you would use for the close button:

```
view.window?.orderOut(self)
```

for miniaturize

```
view.window?.miniaturize(self)
```

and for fullscreenmode (maximise):

```
view.window?.toggleFullScreen(self)
```

If you have any questions let me know.

Have a great day

Answer (score 0):

You can try checked full size content view checkbox of your window.
[image]

Comment: it's already the case. Even with that, in fullscreen the title bar disappear. I know that it's a normal behavior :  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/stylemask/1644530-fullscreen. But I would like to change it